# google app engine Efficient way to put large data in datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I want to store data in a parent child hierarchy. I want to do so using the ndb.put_multi function. The problem is how will i get the corresponding keys of the parents after i have stored parent models using put multi. Kindly suggest a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already used put_multi for the parent keys then you already have them.

Eg

```
list_of_parent_keys = ndb.put_multi(list_of_entities)
child_keys = []
for parent_key in list_of_parent_keys:
  child_key = ndb.Key(Parent, parent_key, Child, child_key)
  child_keys.append(child_key)
```

Comment: thats right , but how will i know that which key is for which parent, because i have list of parents and each entry in the list has a list of childs.

Comment: how do you match the child with the parent? Ids? 
I believe that if the arrays are 1 to 1 you want have any problem. 
But if they are shuffled then you need to match the relationship due to your creteria.

Comment: @omair_77 the keys returned are in the order of the keys you supplied. 
By the `parent_key` you can get the id by: `parent_key.id()`

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to store a "grandparent" or root entity, and have all parent entities reference it in their key:

```
root = BaseClass()
root.put()
parent = Parent(parent=root)
parent.put()
child = Child(parent=parent)
child.put()
```

Now you can examine the child's key using the [Instance methods](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass):

```
parent = child.key.parent()
ancestors = child.key.pairs()
```

The reason you want a root entity is for [Ancestor queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor):

```
parents = Parent.query(ancestor=root)
children = Child.query(ancestor=root)
```

You can then examine the `child.key.parent()` to see its parent key.